# date time as file name for dump file

Tags: tcpdump, packet, gulp

I'm using Gulp to capture packets at 100Mbps to a folder. But I would like to name the files in format job_<'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'>.pcap, but it gives files job.pcap0, job.pcap2 etc. The script I use is  :

```
 sudo ./gulp -f "dst net 24.10.10 or dst net 224.11.11" -i eth1 -r 1024| taskset -c 2 tcpdump -r- -C 2 -w /share/job/job.pcap
```

How do I do get time stamp on the file name?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/share/job/job_`date +%y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`.pcap
```

as logfile name.

Comment: Hi, the filenames are coming in the format but it seems to have an ending number like   job_15_08_05_13_29_58.pcap3, job_15_08_05_13_29_58.pcap4  etc

Comment: That is because the output is bigger than 2000000 bytes. You have specified `-C 2` to define this. Perhaps you should remove this parameter or make the value higher if you do not want this to happen. Check http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump for more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I understand your comment, but that is what I'm trying to do, to create new pcap file every time the limit is reached (2MB), and I was hoping as the file name changed as it is dependent on the date time the tailing number would not come up.

Comment: `tcpdump` gets a 'fixed' filename. It is not aware of the way how it was passed.

Answer (score 1):

`-t` - allows to add a timestamp to the filename

Reference: [gulpman](https://github.com/gsson/gulp/blob/master/gulpman.pdf)

You can then take that filename, extract the integer part & format it to any `date` format as per your requirement.

Comment: But i'm using tcpdump to write the file not Gulp, so this does not work